# Making API request using Request module in node.js app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, node-request

I have the following request call in my node.js app

```
   request({ url:chanURL, qs:chanProperties}, function(err, response, body) {
      if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
      body = JSON.parse(body);

      (function (body) {
        Object.keys(body.items).forEach(function(item) {
            pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
            console.log(pid);
        })
      })();
    })
```

And, I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined`
while processing the response.

The JSON object that I'm trying to work with is

```
{ kind: 'youtube#channelListResponse',
  etag: '"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/B7stMlWJTBpmW2q34yWKIzz8fF8"',
  pageInfo: { totalResults: 1, resultsPerPage: 1 },
  items: 
   [ { kind: 'youtube#channel',
       etag: '"0KG1mRN7bm3nResDPKHQZpg5-do/vV2FFZUI5inz53NuQDJMTs3tdQk"',
       id: 'UCwy6X3JB24VTsDFqMwdO5Jg',
       contentDetails: [Object] } ] }
```

Why does it say `items` is undefined?

And I also would like to know if I want to execute the function within this request wrapper, I need to wrap it inside the parenthesis like I did? I did get syntax error without the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

```
(function (body) { /* ... */ })()
```

You're calling the anonymous function without an argument. `body` is therefore `undefined` inside the function. You should omit the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) - it doesn't help you here.

```
Object.keys(body.items)
```

`Object.keys` returns an array of the property names for an Object. `body.items` is an Array, so you don't need to use it - you should iterate over the object directly.

```
pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads
```

`contentDetails` is an Array. If you mean to use the first element, your code should read: `item.contentDetails[0].relatedPlaylists.uploads`

Making those changes leaves you with:

```
request({ url:chanURL, qs:chanProperties}, function(err, response, body) {
  if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
  body = JSON.parse(body);

  body.items.forEach(function(item) {
      pid = item.contentDetails[0].relatedPlaylists.uploads;
      console.log(pid);
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer, this is really helpful. Would you mind adding how I can structure so I can call another another request call in a chain or using callback? Now I got the playlist ID of my Youtube, I need to make another similar request to get the list of videos using this playlist ID. I know how to get the videos but I'm not sure how to put these two requests together to ultimately get the video data.